# org capture datetree: active timestamp for the day heading

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I want the date in front of the day, captured with `file+olp+datetree` and type `week` as an active date so I can look the entry up in the agenda. The date which I'm talking about is underlined red in the following picture:

[image: part of captured journal with dates underlined]

I know I could add an active timestamp to every entry with `%T`, but then my agenda will be poluted from all entries. I just want the day active so that a single entry is visible in my agenda, allowing me to jump to the daily journal from the agenda.

Section from my capture template:

```
    ("d" "New work journal entry" entry 
    (file+olp+datetree workjournalfile) 
    "* %?" :tree-type week)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try customizing the option `org-datetree-add-timestamp` to `t`. That will *not* make the date you want active, but it will add an active timestamp to the entry on the next line: that should be enough to be able to find it from the agenda.

EDIT: I tested it and it works as the OP expects.

I start with a minimal init file:

```el
(setq org-capture-templates '(
                              ("d" "New work journal entry" entry 
                               (file+olp+datetree "/tmp/work/journal.org") 
                               "* %?" :tree-type week)))

(setq org-agenda-files '("/tmp/work/journal.org"))

(setq org-datetree-add-timestamp t)
```

That adds the capture template the OP describes, adds the journal to the agenda file list and sets the variable as I suggested above.

I start emacs with `emacs -q -l /path/to/minimal/init.el`, capture a bunch of entries and display the agenda. Here's what the `journal.org` file looks like at the end of that:

```
* 2022

** 2022-W39

*** 2022-10-01 Saturday
<2022-10-01 Sat>
**** foo
**** bar
**** baz
```

Note that the time stamp is added to the day entry of the datetree, whereas all subordinate entries do not get one.

The weekly agenda (`M-x org-agenda a` since I have not set up the recommended keybindings in the init file) shows this:

```
Week-agenda (W39):
Monday     26 September 2022 W39
Tuesday    27 September 2022
Wednesday  28 September 2022
Thursday   29 September 2022
Friday     30 September 2022
Saturday    1 October 2022
  journal:    2022-10-01 Saturday
Sunday      2 October 2022
```

As you can see, a single entry for the date, not three entries for the items. Pressing `<RET>` on the agenda item takes me to the day entry in the journal.

Isn't that what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: I've deleted my last comment because it clearly was wrong: this answer is absolutely correct and fixes my problem. Thank you very much!